How to Properly Use Subprocess Open Child Process Then Allow For Continuance Of Script Once Program Closed
So I've been working to automate the process of building a linux distribution and am currently building the program to select from a dictionary the proper block device to run fdisk on in order to properly partition the disk. This is a small portion of the program however I don't understand sub-process.
#!/usr/bin/env python3

''' gentoo building basic of the distribution '''

import logging
import os
import sys
import shutil
import subprocess
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
import json
import operator
import signal


def return_blockdev_name():
        process = subprocess.run("lsblk --json -o NAME,SIZE,UUID,MOUNTPOINT,PATH,FSTYPE ".split(), capture_output=True, text=True)
        return json.loads(process.stdout)

block_devices = return_blockdev_name()

print(block_devices)

print(block_devices.items())
class BlockDevice:
    def __init__(self, block_devices):
        self.block_devices = block_devices.get("blockdevices",[])
        for device in self.block_devices:
                for k, v in block_devices.items():
                        setattr(self, k, v)

        def __iter__(self):
                for value in self.block_devices.values():
                        yield value

        def blockdeviceiter(self):
                return iter(self.block_device.values())

                
block_device_selection_list = BlockDevice(block_devices)
print(block_device_selection_list.blockdevices)
block_device_selection = input("enter your usb block device: " )
for item in block_device_selection_list.blockdevices:
        if item['name'] == block_device_selection:
                print("success")
                print(item)
                print(item['path'])
                args = item['path']
                process = subprocess.run(['fdisk', args])    
                process.kill()   
        else:
                print("try again")



booted = "UEFI" if os.path.exists("/sys/firmware/efi") else "BIOS"
print("The system booted with %s" % booted)
sys.exit(0)


I'm expecting subprocess.run to open fdisk, which it does, then process.kill() to kill whatever childprocess is created by the process assigned to variable process, which I believe it does. What i want however is the space to enter a keyboard interrupt or hypothetically come across some error and still continue running with the rest of script. im imagining there's a function that handle's keyboard interruption error in the form (option, error) = ??? and I can attach that to a conditional statement. This is my first time using subprocess.

subprocess.run() doesn't return until the process has finished, you don't need to use process.kill().

You can use subprocess.Popen(). It returns immediately instead of waiting for the program to finish. Then you can use process.kill() to kill the process later.

.blockdevices should be .block_devices.

I don't really understand why you want to kill the process immediately after you start it.

i originally was using Popen, that's why process.kill() is there. Using Popen to return immediately however, doesnt seem to allow me to actually use fdisk from the commandline. Maybe i was using the wrong options. Also thank you didnt notice .blockdevices.

I think what you've got should work. It will start fdisk, which will run interactively. When you exit from it, the script will continue.

The problem you're having is with an interrupt character? You need to run fdisk in a new process group. That way, the interrupt character will only go to fdisk, not also to Python.

oh okay, gotcha.

I don't think there's a built-in way to do this in subprocess.run() (there's a CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP flag, but it's only for Windows, not Linux). I haven't found a simple explanation of how to do this.

welp, i'll just have to figure something out. I suppose it's not the end of the world.
